# Safe area doen't move items

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have an app, where there's a hamburger menu button. That button is constrained like this:

[image]

However, the top space to `safe area` constraint doesn't appear to work, since my button renders like this : (simulator screenshot, but it renders the same on a physical device)

[image]

Is there anyone who experienced this? Or is this perhaps a bug within xcode? The problem exists on the iPhone X, but not on other models.

Thanks.
-- Edit

This is what it looks like in IB:

[image]

Comment: Hard to say without some more information. You might have something else going on in your view controller that could be causing this. Try posting any relevant view controller code you might have.

Comment: how it looks in IB ?

Comment: @NazarLisovyi Added a screenshot

Comment: "I have an app, where there's a hamburger menu button." - there's your problem :P

Comment: @ilikecode can you double click on the Top Space constraint and post a screenshot? Are there any other elements that are constrained to the top of the safe are? If there are, are they working alright?

Comment: What are the `first item` and `second item` in the top constraint?

Comment: @Fogmeister `menubutton.top`, `safe area.top`